# Orbit of an element in $S_3$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, permutations

Short question:

> Define \begin{array}{rccc}
> \rho: & S_3 \times \{1,2,3\} & \rightarrow & \{1,2,3\} \\
> & (\sigma,i) & \mapsto & \sigma(i) 
> \end{array}
>   What is $|\text{Orb}(2)|?$ |

---

The orbit is the possible outputs where $2$ can get sent to if elements of the group act on it. Isn't the orbit in this case not just all of $\{1,2,3 \}$, so $|\text{Orb}(2)|=3$.

This would mean that $|\text{Orb}(i)|=n$ for $i \in \{ 1, 2, \dots n\}$ if we extend this example to $S_n$. Am I getting this correctly?

Comment: "Isn't the orbit in this case not just all of {1,2,3}". Indeed, but why ?

Comment: "This would mean that |Orb()|= for ∈{1,2,…} if we extend this example to ". You have to prove this. Indeed, but why ?

Comment: Because $( 1 \ 2 \ 3 ) \in S_3$ and similarly $(1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4 \dots \ n) \in S_n$

Comment: I think that's why

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense. Do you know what is an element of the orbit ?

Comment: $\text{Orb}(i)$ is the set of elements that $i$ gets sent to if the group acts on this element, since a group is closed under composition, it containing a cycle generator like $(1 \ 2 \ 3 ) $i s sufficient (for our example) for every single element to appear in the orbit. Since we then also get  $(1 \  3\ 2 ) $ and $(1)(2)(3)$ by repeated composition. The first cycle tells us 3 is an output, the second tells us that 1 is also in there and the identity tells us that 2 can get sent to itself. Therefore $\{ 1,2,3\}$ is the orbit.

Comment: That's a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\text{Orb}(i)$ is the set of elements that $i$ gets sent to if the group acts on this element, since a group is closed under composition, it containing a cycle generator like $(1 \ 2 \ 3)$ is sufficient (for our example) for every single element to appear in the orbit. Since we then also get $(1 \ 3 \ 2)$ and $(1)(2)(3)$ by repeated composition. The first cycle tells us 3 is an output, the second tells us that 1 is also in there and the identity tells us that 2 can get sent to itself. Therefore $\{1,2,3\}$ is indeed the orbit. This has cardinality $3$

Similarly we can make this case that the cycle $( 1 \ 2 \ 3 \dots n)$ generates an $n$-cycle when it acts upon $S_n$ therefore the orbit will also be all of  $\{  1 \ 2 \ 3 \dots n \}$ .